# how to classifying with not ordianal data

Tags: machine-learning, svm

i'm new to machine learning field.
Trying to classify 10 people with a their phone call logs.

The phone call logs look like this

```
UserId      IsInboundCall    Duration    PhoneNumber(hashed)
1           false            23          1011112222
2           true             45          1033334444
```

Trained with this kind of 8700 logs with SVM from *sklearn* gives a result is accuracy 88%

I have a several question about this result and 
what is a proper way to use some not ordinal data(ex. phone number)

1. I'm not sure using a hashed phone number as a feature but this multi class classifiers accuracy is not bad, is it just a coincidence?
2. How to use not oridnal data as a feature?
3. If this classifier have to classify more 1000 classes(more 1000 users), is SVM still work on that case?

Any advice is helpful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try the SVM without Phone number as a feature to get a sense of how much impact it has.

2) In order to avoid Ordinal Data you can either transform into a number or use a 1 of K approach. Say you added an Phone OS field with possible values `{IOS, Android, Blackberry}` you can represent this as a number `0,1,2` or as 3 features `(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)`.

3) The SVM will still give good results as long as the data is approximately linearly separable. To achieve this you might need to add more features and map into a different feature space (an RBF kernel is a good start).